# Crear widget dinamico para el sidebar home en Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Sólo he logrado crear un widget pero para el dashboard del admin y yo lo quiero para el home

```
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup','dcms_agregar_widget');

//Agregar Widget
function dcms_agregar_widget(){
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('id_mi_widget','Mi Widget de Ejemplo','dcms_mostrar_widget');
}

//Mostrar Widget
function dcms_mostrar_widget(){
    echo "Hola desde mi nuevo Widget";
}
```